# Atomic repository...in english please

Tags: linux, yum

Simple question, hopefully a simple answer:

I am new to Linux servers, and my hosting company offered me a tip to:

> You may want to add the Plesk
>   repository provided by Atomic Turtle.

I know how to install it (they offered good insturctions), but i have no clue what it is...help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plesk is admin panel, something similar to DirectAdmin. Lets you (and your users) to administrate server via www, in browser.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesk

Repository is something like a database of various linux programs (in this case only, repository as a term is much broader). Your software, responsible for managing (downloading and installing) another soft uses repositories to download from. Said software can be apt, or Synaptic package manager, or whatever else.

So in plain English, its like this: add atomic repository address to your repositories list so that you would be able to easily download and install Plesk control panel :)

Answer (score 1):

Plesk is a control panel for webhosting, as I'm sure you know. As with most things nowadays, it allows you to install various extra features or addins.

Atomic Turtle's repository is a set of such addins as well as a set of plesk-friedly Linux applications that help you administer your server. (though nowadays its more a site for his own Linux disto, ASL)

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent reason of mine for using the Atomic repositories has been upgrading PHP from 5.1 to 5.2/5.3. You can't do this without crafting a repository script of yours or using a ready-made one like the Atomic.